# Simple_form_for not using AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I got a weird problem with my form:

```
= simple_form_for([@item, @item_comment], :remote => true, id: "new_item_comment", :url => item_item_comments_path(@item)) do |f|
  = f.input :comment, :label => false
  = f.submit "Save", :class => "btn_save left"
```

Which in my opinion should call:

```
Started POST "/de-de/items/20150423/item_comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-23 12:29:33 +0200
Processing by ItemCommentsController#create as JSON
```

but instead I get it as HTML:

```
Started POST "/de-de/items/20150423/item_comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-23 12:29:33 +0200
Processing by ItemCommentsController#create as HTML
```

It used to work but without changing these parts, it only uses HTML.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

**--- Update 1 ---**

I added these lines to my coffeescript:

```
$('form[data-remote]').submit (e)->
   e.preventDefault()
   $.rails.handleRemote $('form[data-remote]')
```

And it works but I'm not really satisfied with this solution since I don't know what caused the problem.

Comment: check that rails - jquery scripts are loaded properly

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why do you expect "/contracts/" in the path when contracts are not referenced in the form? The POST you see is the POST I would expect. Did you say this form as it is worked at one point?

Comment: That was my bad, I must have pasted the wrong line. Anyhow, the point is, that it's not treating it as JSON but HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it happened to me in 2 cases:

1. I had a file input on the form (which forces ruby to skip `remote: true` option)
2. I had troubles with jquery-ujs javascript file (which actually processes rails html attrs)

So please check your generated html if it has `<form .... data-remote='true'..>` and check that jquery-ujs (or whatever handler you want to use) is included in a page javascripts.

If you are still having troubles after this, you can put a breakpoint somewhere in [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L101)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. However, no success. It got `data-remote="true"` and `jquery` and `jquery-ujs` are both being loaded.

Comment: Breakpoint not working, clicking submit button immediately loads the next page which is blank.

Comment: Is there a chance that some other javascript submits form?

Comment: Yes, probably but very hard to find that line of code... Still trying.

Comment: @Cojones can you check **initiator** of the http request (non-ajax) in a **Chrome-> Inspector->Network** tab